# Xamarin draw cyrillic text in CGContext

Tags: c#, encoding, xamarin, cyrillic, cgcontextdrawimage

First, here is my code, I'm drawing first letter of nickname in userpic:

```
            context.TranslateCTM (0, rect.Height);
            context.ScaleCTM (1, -1);
            context.SelectFont ("Helvetica", 140.0f, CGTextEncoding.MacRoman);
            context.SetFillColor (UIColor.White.CGColor);
            context.SetTextDrawingMode (CGTextDrawingMode.Fill);
            var tsize = new NSString (Text).StringSize (UIFont.FromName ("Helvetica-Bold", 140.0f));
            context.ShowTextAtPoint (rect.Width / 2 - tsize.Width / 2, rect.Height / 2 - tsize.Height / (2.7f), Text);
```

So for english words it works nice, but when I try to draw cyrillic symbols("ЛвУамау" for example) it draws '_' symbol, how can I fix it?

[image]  [image]